# invalid number error when inserting a row in oracle

Tags: oracle

I need to insert a row to a table in oracle.

```
insert into policy_tab values ('4325','29-APR-98','29-APR-2007',32424,(select ref(a) from agent_tab a where a.nic='242424v'),claim_ntty(
claim_t('25-APR-2005','25-JUN-2005'),
claim_t('26-APR-2005','26-JUN-2005')
));
```

But when I executed it will show this error. "ORA-01722: invalid number ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SQL", line 1721"

```
create type policy_ty as object(
 pid char(5),
 sDate date,
 eDate date,
 premium number(10,2),
 agent ref agent_ty,
 claims claim_ntty
);

create table policy_tab of policy_ty(
 pid primary key,
 agent SCOPE IS agent_tab
)
nested table claims store as claim_nttab;

create type claim_t AS OBJECT(
 eDate date,
 amount number(10,2)
);
create type claim_ntty as table of claim_t;

create type agent_ty as object(
 nic char(10),
 name varchar(50),
 address varchar(50),
 contactNo contactNo_vaty
) NOT FINAL;

create table agent_tab of agent_ty(
 nic primary key
);
```

So how to resolve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the first look you need to use like below. However the information provided is not sufficient to resolve the issue. Related Objects defintion as well needed.

This has to be changed - `'29-APR-98'` to `'29-APR-1998'`

```
INSERT INTO policy_tab
        VALUES (
                  '4325',
                  '29-APR-1998',
                  '29-APR-2007',
                  32424,
                  (SELECT REF (a)
                     FROM agent_tab a
                    WHERE a.nic = '242424v'),
                  claim_ntty (claim_t ('25-APR-2005', '25-JUN-2005'),
                              claim_t ('26-APR-2005', '26-JUN-2005')));
```

Edit:

Second observation. You created the below object:

```
create type claim_t AS OBJECT(
eDate date,
amount number(10,2)
);
```

And using it like:

```
claim_ntty (claim_t ('25-APR-2005', '25-JUN-2005'),
                                  claim_t ('26-APR-2005', '26-JUN-2005')));
```

Second Argument should be `number` not `date`.

So your insert should be:

```
INSERT INTO policy_tab
        VALUES (
                  '4325',
                  '29-APR-1998',
                  '29-APR-2007',
                  32424,
                  (SELECT REF (a)
                     FROM agent_tab a
                    WHERE a.nic = '242424v'),
                  claim_ntty (claim_t ('25-APR-2005', 123), claim_t ('26-APR-2005', 456)));
```

Comment: @A.Wen Post your table `policy_tab`
 definition   as well and result you get from `claim_ntty` and your `select` stament

Comment: @A.Wen Please update comepletely. I cannot see full information. First 4 input list seems correct so the error lies definitly in last 2.

Comment: Oh. got it. Thanks

Comment: @A.Wen `'29-APR-1998'` is not a date - it is a string literal. If a user changes their `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` session parameter then the insert will fail (without having modified your DML statements). Either use a date literal `DATE '1998-04-29'` or explicitly convert the string literal to a date using `TO_DATE( '29-APR-1998', 'DD-MON-YYYY', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=English' )`